# CM10.1 Wifi issue

Tags: wi-fi, cyanogenmod, custom-roms, htc-one-x

I just flashed my *HTC One X AT&T Build number 1.73.502.1 710RD ATT US edition* with **CM 10.1** as described at [CM10.1 Android 4.2.1 ROM for AT&T One X/One XL](http://onexroot.com/one-xl-roms/cm10-1-android-4-2-1-rom-for-att-one-xone-xl/)

Everything seems fine, but once I connect my device with wifi, its gets connected but data is not being transferred. Does someone has idea if this is bug or is there any solution for this ?

I am trying to connect via my broadband router. Sometimes, it shows signal of being connected, but the data connection speed is too less and gets disconnected. Even Airdroid doesn't work, it should have work when being on same network.

Comment: Is that some hotspot which requires authentication via a browser, maybe? Lots of hotels use it that way, and it looks exactly the same: Connected, but no data until you authenticated via their webpage.

Comment: No, I am trying to connect via my broadband router. Sometimes, it shows signal of being connected, but the data connection speed is too less and gets disconnected. Even Airdroid doesn't work, it should have work when being on same n/w

Comment: Are you using CM 10.1 nightly?

Comment: hmm, I don't know whether its nightly, can you please check this link, http://onexroot.com/one-xl-roms/cm10-1-android-4-2-1-rom-for-att-one-xone-xl/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I unchecked **Automatic date & time** and **Automatic time zone** on **Date & time** settings, everything worked perfectly.